# Parse error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format. - PHPMailer in Swift 3.0

Tags: php, json, swift3, xcode8, phpmailer

I have these swift 3.0 code to post JSON data into php mysql database.

**test.swift**

```
let url             = URL(string: "http://localhost:test.php")
let session         = URLSession.shared
let request         = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.httpMethod  = "POST"
let valueToSend     = "data1=&data2"
request.httpBody    = valueToSend.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
let myAlert         = UIAlertController(title: "Confirm", message: "are you sure ?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let cancel          = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil)
let okaction        = UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:
    {
        action in

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {
                (data, response, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    return
                }
                else {
                    do {
                        if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as? [String: String]
                        {
                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                let message = Int(json["message"]!)
                                if(message == 1)
                                {
                                    let myViewController:ViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
                                    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                                    let navigationController = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: myViewController)
                                    appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = navigationController
                                    appDelegate.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

                                    let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Success !", message: "sent !", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                                    myAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Noted", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                                    navigationController.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                                    return
                                }
                                else { return }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch let parseError { print("Parse error: \(parseError.localizedDescription)") }
        }
    })
    task.resume()

    }
    )
myAlert.addAction(okaction)
myAlert.addAction(cancel)
self.present(myAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

So far, I managed to send the data into database and email works fine. I can received the email using PHPMailer. But the problem occur with x code can't read PHPMailer code.

Error display in my console like this because of PHPMailer. When I removed PHPMailer code, it works fine.

> "Parse error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the
>   correct format."

My goal is, I don't want this error appears because UIAlertAction will stuck on the same page. It will not go into rootController because of that error.

Is there any way to fix this problem ? Btw, here's my php code

**test.php**

```
<?php
    require 'database/connect.php';
    global $connect;
    require_once 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    if (isset($_POST['data1'])) {
        $data1      = $_POST['data1'];
        $sql        = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE data1 = '$data1'";
        $result     = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        if ($result && mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
            {}

            $output = array('message' => '1');
            echo json_encode($output);

            $add = "INSERT INTO table (data1) VALUES ('$data1')";
            $run = mysqli_query($connect,$add);

            $mail = new PHPMailer;                              
            $mail->isSMTP();                                       
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                                
            $mail->Username = 'test@gmail.com';               
            $mail->Password = '*****';                            
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
            $mail->Port = 587;                                     
            $mail->setFrom('email@email.com.my', 'Mailer');  
            $mail->addAddress('test@email','Receiver');   
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
            $mail->Subject = 'Test';
            $mail->Body    = 'Test';
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';
            if(!$mail->send()) 
            {
                    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
                    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } 
            else 
            {
                    echo 'Message has been sent';
            }            
            exit();

        mysqli_free_result($result);
        }
        else 
        {}
    }
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to run PHP code from Swift? Why not send your message using swift? It's really not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: There has been no problem sending data from swift to php . just x code can't read PHPMailer code .  That's the problem i'm facing right now . .

Comment: I'm using PHP code to send an email . .

Comment: Xcode will open PHP files just fine, but it won't run them as it has no built-in PHP support. What do you mean by "can't read PHPMailer code"? Also, you don't need to use Xcode for this at all, any text editor will do.

Comment: What I mean is, when I add PHPMailer code inside test.php, the I rebuild apps in x code and try to send the data into web server . the console in x code display the error "Parse error: The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format." . But when I remove PHPMailer code section inside php file. My apps can send the data normally. no error at all .

Comment: the problem start in this line "$mail = new PHPMailer;" until this line "else 
            {
                    echo 'Message has been sent';
            }  " . . . X code show an error when I add these code inside php file. I hope you understand what I'm trying to explain.

Comment: Well there's nothing wrong with the PHP code, so this must be an Xcode config problem.

Comment: I think so too. because I use the same way in Android Studio and it work just fine. . I'm not sure why its not working on x code .